# Send integer to database with parameterized query

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, ado

I'm having trouble sending data other than strings(varchar) to a stored procedure, through an ado parameterized query.

Let's assume I am just trying to send a single `int` parameter, and there is a stored procedure that accepts a single int. When I run the code I get `type mismatch`.

If I change the `int` to a `String` and the stored procedure to accept `varchar` it works. Also, the stored procedure works with other code written in VBScript and PHP. So I'm guessing it isn't the stored procedure.

I'm assuming it has something to do with `.createParameter` line - type or length
or maybe the attributes line a few lines below that.  I've tried many different combinations, but to no avail.
Let me know if I need to clean the code up more. Thanks.

```
            command.ActiveConnection = myconn;
            command.CommandText = this.procedure;  
            command.CommandType = 4;
            prmCount = 0;

            //Build Parmeters
            for(var p in this.params){  //<---  I set these params earlier -- they behave as expected

                if(this.params.hasOwnProperty(p)){

                    command.Parameters.Append(

                         command.CreateParameter(
                               "", 
                               this.params[p].type,         // <-- i've tried pretty much every value for the type - 3, 19, 14, 5, ...
                               this.params[p].direction,    // <-- this is the same for all inputs
                               this.params[p].length        // <-- i send null for this value
                         )

                    );

                    //A Fix for Null String values
                    if(this.params[p].value === null || this.params[p].value === ""){
                        command.Parameters(prmCount).Attributes = 64;
                    }

                    //Some examples show adding a `.Attributes` value for some integers
                    //However this didn't help
                    //
                    //if(this.params[p].type === 3){
                        //command.Parameters(prmCount).Attributes = 128;
                    //}

                    command.Parameters(prmCount).Value = this.params[p].value;  //<-- Set the value here
                    prmCount+=1;

                }
            }

            record = command.Execute();
```

Comment: Is this javascript in "ASP-Classic" (instead of asp.net)? Then please update the tags to get better traffic.

Comment: huh,  i did.  I think who ever edited my post changed it. Because I had javascript too.

Comment: have you tried **parseInt(this.params[p].value)** ?

Comment: @Ali Sheikhpour  I `parseInt()` earlier when i build the `this.params` object.  But i will verify this just to make sure.